# dúvida Array.push() Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmo

Olá! Alguém saberia me dizer por que o método push só está salvando o último item na array `newArr`?
O meu objetivo é extrair uma array com a permutação dos valores passados e no `console.log()` sai certinho, porém quando tento jogar os resultados numa array através do método `push()` saí desse jeito que mostro abaixo, no output.

```
 function permAlone(str) {    
    var newArr = [];

    function generate(n,arr){
        var c = [];
        var i = 0; //i while

        for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
            c[i] = 0;
        }

        console.log(arr);
        newArr.push(arr);    

        while(i < n){           
            if(c[i] < i){
                if(i%2==0){
                    var aux = arr[0];
                    arr[0] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = aux;
                }
                else{
                    var aux = arr[c[i]];
                    arr[c[i]] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = aux;                   
                }
                console.log(arr)
                newArr.push(arr);
                c[i]+=1;
                i = 0;
            }
            else{
                c[i] = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }       
    }
    generate(str.length, str.split(''));
    console.log('newArr');
    console.log(newArr)
}
permAlone('aab');
```

Output:

```
 [ 'a', 'a', 'b' ]
[ 'a', 'a', 'b' ]
[ 'b', 'a', 'a' ]
[ 'a', 'b', 'a' ]
[ 'a', 'b', 'a' ]
[ 'b', 'a', 'a' ]
newArr
[ [ 'b', 'a', 'a' ],
  [ 'b', 'a', 'a' ],
  [ 'b', 'a', 'a' ],
  [ 'b', 'a', 'a' ],
  [ 'b', 'a', 'a' ],
  [ 'b', 'a', 'a' ] ]
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: @OnoSendai eu quero que meu `newArr` tenha os 6 arrays resultantes do `console.log()`. Não sei qual o termo correto entre adicionar um array ou concatenar, mas acho que seria adicionar mesmo.

Comment: Um *array* é um objeto. Você está adicionando à `newArr` um novo objeto, que por acaso é um *array*. O resultado final é um *array* (newArr) que possui um objeto em sua coleção interna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está adicionando um array (`arr`) como um *objeto* à coleção interna de `newArr`.

Se você deseja concatenar os elementos de `arr` com os elementos de `newArr`, ao invés de

```
newArr.push(arr);
```

Utilize `.concat()`:

```
newArr = newArr.concat(arr);
```